# Prestashop / Smarty - Extend a module template file in the theme

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

Is there a way to extend a module template file (view) in the theme ?

Because when I try to extend

```
{extends file='module:my_module/views/templates/front/view.tpl'}
```

I have obviously an infinite recursive call.

I need something like :

```
{extends file='parent:module:my_module/views/templates/front/view.tpl'}
```

or

```
{extends file='parent_module:my_module/views/templates/front/view.tpl'}
```

Or another way to extend a module template without having an infinite recursive loop.

Thank you.

Comment: are you tring to use a module's tpl in your theme or you trying to change a module's tpl for your theme ?

Comment: I want to change a module's tpl for my theme, but I don't want to override the whole file of the module, but only a specific part. That's why I want to extend a module's tpl file in my child theme.